# POST http://localhost:3000/data 400 (Bad Request) when trying to send data from client to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, backend

Hey guys so i've got some problem with sending data from client-side to server-side.
Basically i have a function that on click is setting variable called categorySearch to a string e.g categorySearch = "pork" and send it to server; But for some reason i keep getting error mentioned in the title. Here's some code:
Client Side

```
function getRecipes(category){
    const categorySearch = category.alt;
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: categorySearch
    }
    const response = fetch('/data', options);
    console.log(response);
}
```

Server-side

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
require('dotenv').config();
const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log('listening at 3000'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "1mb"}));

app.post('/data', (request, repsonse) => {
    console.log(request.body);
})
```

Not sure what i did wrong, i haven't worked much with backend so don't have much knowledge either, any help very appreciated :)

My end-goal for that is to be able to send the data that users enters or in this case clicks on to the server, then in the server-side make an api call to the search engine, take the data i need, send it back to client-server and display it on the page.

Comment: ` 'Content-type': 'application/json'` remove this and use ` 'Content-type': 'text/plain'`

Comment: he have configured json in sever `app.use(express.json())`, then how text/plain works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Reason**:-

The 400 Bad Request Error is an HTTP response status code that indicates that the server was unable to process the request sent by the client due to invalid syntax

as per your code your sending data from client as json and retrieving that in your server as plain text, so instead of sending it as `application/json` use `text/plain` or remove that header part so it will work fine,  check out the below-attached code.

Client-side:-

```
function getRecipes(category){
const categorySearch = category.alt;
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'text/plain',
    }, // or remove this headers section
    bodydata: categorySearch
}
 const response = fetch('/data', options);
 console.log(response);
}
```

Server-side:

```
app.post('/data', (request, response) => {
 console.log(request.body.bodydata);
})
```

hope this will give you some idea about the error. read here more about [400 error](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/400-bad-request#:%7E:text=The%20400%20Bad%20Request%20Error,client%20due%20to%20invalid%20syntax.)

Comment: Thank you, that helped ! Now there is another problem, it doesn't return text i wanted, i just get empty object as in "{}". I logged the variable and definitely it is getting text, so not sure what's wrong ?

Comment: it doesn't return text I wanted what does it mean? where did you get an empty object {}?

Comment: Ah sorry i didn't explained that well. On the server-side it should get that data from the client-side and log it with this :
```app.post('/data', (request, repsonse) => {
 console.log(request.body);
})```

Comment: check what you're getting only by `console.log(request)`

Comment: check my updated ans i changed `body` to `bodydata`

Comment: It returns undefined. I think problem is on the client side because when i logged just "request" it showed my like a 1000 lines of information and at the end there was ```body: {}```, so it does get it from the client, it's just empty :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218351/discussion-between-codebug-and-pawel-krzesinski).

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRecipes(category){
    const categorySearch = category.alt;
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: categorySearch
    }
    const response = fetch('/data', options);
    console.log(response);
}
```

To resolve this problem, no need to change Content-type it is alright.
Just remember when you'll ever use "application/json" content type, then sending data in body must be an OBJECT/ARRAY.
In your case "body: categorySearch" categorySearch must be an object or an array.
that's it, I hope it'll solve your problem.
Thankyou